# gcloud-cli interfering with podman - any workaround?

Tags: docker, podman, gcloud-cli

gcloud-cli seem to be interfering with podman (and may be docker)

Any workaround for this?

```bash
#This command has nothing to do with gcloud-cli, likely gcloud is messing with environment
podman pull registry.redhat.io/rhel8/mariadb-105


Error: 1 error occurred:
    * error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `You do not currently have an active account selected. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing for more information.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the following files to check if there any credential helpers configured for the registries in question:

- `~/.docker/config.json`
- `~/.config/containers/auth.json`
- `~/.config/containers/registries.conf`